# Is there a way delete an item inside an array which is stored in firestore collection without using its document id?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a todo list with React and firebase, I have placed a delete button beside every item . Is there a way to delete the item without having to fetch its document id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make any changes at all to any document without knowing its ID.  The APIs for updating documents require that you provide a DocumentReference, and the only way you can build a DocumentReference is using a document ID.

If you don't know the document ID, you will have to query the collection, iterate the results, and somehow locate the document you're looking for.